# How to automate Test driven development (TDD) syntax for websites coded in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, web-testing

Having this syntax, how can i automate it and what IDE shall i use ?

```
When I fill in "Email" with ""
  And I press "Yes – this is my email address"
  Then I should see "Email must be completed"
  When I fill in "Email" with "emna@mail.com"
  And I press "Yes – this is my email address"
Then a new user should exist
```

Shall i use javascript for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax shown is Gherkin. It can be automated with Cucumber or Spinach.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby

https://github.com/codegram/spinach

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)